# Universal family of the Hilbert scheme of one point.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If $X$ is projective over a base scheme $S$, then its Hilbert scheme of one point is just itself. i.e.
\begin{equation}
\text{Hilb}^1(X)=X
\end{equation} 
What about the universal family? i.e. there is a subschem $\text{Univ}^1(X) \hookrightarrow X \times_S X$ such that any fiber of $\text{Univ}^1(X) \rightarrow X$ is a degree $1$ point. Does anyone know what is this universal family generally?

Comment: Use the diagonal.